# Codeigniter Showing database error when redirected from facebook login

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create facebook login,

Login button on my site redirect me to facebook, for login, ask to permit my application for required permission ('offline_access,email etc').

When user allow it returns to my inside page(User Page). Also add the user data to my database if user's facebook id is not in my database.

but it is not working every time (in both case if user in database or not). sometime it gives following error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

This is my login function which generate the fb login url

```
$this->load->library('facebook');
        $user = $this->facebook->getUser();
        $data['loginUrl']="";
        $data['logoutUrl']="";
        if ($user) {
            try {
                $data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me');
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e);
                $user = null;
            }
        }
        if ($user) {
            $data['logoutUrl'] = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(array(
                'next' => ASITEURL . '/login/logout'));
        } else {
            $param['redirect_uri'] = ASITEURL . '/login/checkLogInfo';
            $param['scope'] = 'email,publish_stream,user_birthday';
            $data['loginUrl'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($param);
        }
        $this->load->view('login/login', $data);
```

checkLogInfo is function which handles the session and database code.

Fb Redirect me to following url after successful login (and granting permission first time):

```
http://mysite.com/login/checkLogInfo?state=4d59a4fe681ae940f036393c895d1c57&code=AQA3gAnl86izonBQyh8wThjNZuNowX1h6YBlGkeIiaQU__DFHDywC9nIgWYzW22EaxkVJB5nudjnNd4uElNs1-SFa0Ej_h4_4AAaYh4bLf9_HBpUiaSzbuDUcYg0WIIg0B4mvKq0_H3W3xH0gcKPWL1Fbrp3ff3IVt0unFIIeyevRb9oZwPld6NTKtU_tHxrQFtEdMgE6S2dwPcrbyY54g82#_=_
```

Database Setting :

```
    $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
    $db['default']['username'] = 'root';
    $db['default']['password'] = '';
    $active_group = 'default';
    $active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['database'] = 'mydb';
    $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
    $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Thanks

Comment: Problem is in your database settings. Check those.

Comment: Database settings are ok as it is working some times. I think problem is with url (fb redirect url).but i'm not getting the exact issue.

Comment: An url can not cause the database connection error. What driver you are using? Do you have multiple connections?

Comment: no mysql database **($db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';)**

Comment: Edit your question and provide the database settings. And what no mysql means?

Comment: is other pages working with the same config?

Comment: yes, all other pages working...

Comment: btw, what is your OS in which you are running the server?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17856/discussion-between-ravi-and-itachi)

Comment: I've had this issue with Codeigniter if something causes the DB to corrupt. It will work off and on giving absolutely no real reason for why it fails. My guess is that code is fine and something else has screwed up the DB itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.database settings of Application are loading dynamically depends on URL (changes host name if URL contains 'QA'). So whenever facebook redirect me to url containing **QA** (as  the given url in question) it was showing me error...

Thanks itachi and Rick Calder.